# How can i export a chart and multiple rows from an excel sheet to pdf

Tags: vba, excel

I have an organogram chart in excel and few rows based on which this organogram chart is constructed. Both the chart and data rows are in the same worksheet.

I need to get this chart printed on the upper half of the pdf and the data rows just below the chart.

I have figured out how to get both chart and data rows printed individually in the pdf but i am unable to figure out how to get the data rows printed below the chart on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Select everything you want to be exported. Select **Right Click** / **Set Print Area**. This way you should be able to export what you have selected explicitly.

If you have difficulty printing everything on one page, play around with **Scaling** properties on the **Print Preview** page and try exporting again.